# Physical puzzle in four parts

Tags: mechanical-puzzles, visual, jigsaw-puzzle

This is simple and has a glaringly clear solution.

Instructions:

> - Print
> - Cut
> - Assemble

To make it a proper puzzle and avoid half-solutions: The solution I'm looking for

- has all pieces touching two others
- produces an image people would generally considers not scrambled
- is rotated with what appears to be the "ground" showing at the bottom

Get puzzling!

> [image]

Comment: Sorry folks. I couldn't resist. ;c)

Comment: Where's the challenge??

Comment: @rand al'thor: Where is your solution? Never said it is a DIFFICULT puzzle. But a (hopefully) well defined one at least. (Don't take this too serious.)

Comment: I'm not posting a solution because I can't be bothered to go to a printer, cut out and assemble the pieces, scan in the completed puzzle, and work out how to upload a picture to SE; no other reason :-)

Comment: @randal'thor Valid answer! :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Someone had to do it.

> [image]

I liked the ancient math one more though.

Comment: Perfect. Bonus point if you can show you have actually printed it!

Comment: I'm too low on toner ATM.  Otherwise I would!

Comment: Technically I did print (screen) it :P

Comment: +1 because you have (still) discovered something not completely enough defined in this puzzle. QED.