# How would you like your face? Scrambled?

Tags: visual, story, knowledge

Great!

First day on the job here at the F.B.I., and I've got a mess on my hands.

Someone hacked into Langley's mainframe and scrambled twelve of the mugshots that we have on file, and it's ***my*** job to reconstruct them, restoring these records of dangerous criminals to their original states.

The Director told me that from now on anyone who forgets to make sure that the mugshot logs are backed up before going home for the night will be waterboarded *with extreme predjudice*.

I've arranged the mess on my desk as follows:

[image: group]
(click to enlarge)

In the near future I may assemble them in flip-book fashion so that I can see each image in rapid succession. Let's see how this goes.

I need some help figuring out how to rearrange the pieces in order to find out who these hoodlums are.

> Can you help me identify these twelve troublemakers?

Now that the puzzle is solved and we have several nice reconstructions, here's my flip-book:

> [image: flipbook]

Didn't want my GIF to go to waste and some of them are pretty funny...

Comment: This is as true to a [puzzle-question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5578/5840) as can be... Race to the GIMP!

Comment: Dang, the CIA must really be hurting for recruits if they're asking a first day FBI agent to solve this solo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Image:

> [image]

The Names:

> 1. Mel Gibson
>  2. Charlie Sheen
>  3. Elvis
>  4. Paul Reuben
>  5. Justin Bieber
>  6. Robert Downey Jr
>  7. OJ Simpson
>  8. Kobe Bryant
>  9. John Belushi
>  10. Paris Hilton
>  11. Lindsay Lohan
>  12. Reese Witherspoon

Comment: A match I think except one I did not know - your #8 - I know the name, but I only play the game I don't watch it :) Shouldn't have spent so long faffing in MS Paint :p

Comment: @JonathanAllan I'm not 100% sure too for some of them. But your unscrambled picture is perfectly sliced... I was lazy and did it automatically :)

Comment: Automatically? With what?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Gimp, vertical and horizontal guidelines (which didn't pass evenly through all tiles edges because they are not precise), then with plugin "Guillotine to layers". I mean only slicing is, well, semi-automatic.

Comment: Probably also worth noting that all of these people would have real mugshots, since they've all been arrested for various reasons.

Comment: This is noted in the question itself.

Comment: Well (**and quickly**) done! The images were all found searching *Google Images* with the query *"celebrity mugshots."* Not sure if are *all*  really authentic mugs or not, but no reason to believe otherwise.

Answer (score 12):

They are

> the mug shots of famous (American?) people
>
>  Here's an unscrambled version:
>  [image]
>
>  Not really people I know much about, so some may be wrong and I don't know bottom-left, but...
>
>  Elvis Presley ---- Lindsay Lohan(?) ---- OJ Simpson ---- Reese Witherspoon(?)
>  Justin Bieber(?) ---- Charlie Sheen ---- Robert Downey Jr. ---- Paul Reubens(?)
>  ? ---- John Belushi ---- Mel Gibson ---- Paris Hilton

Comment: By *far* the best job of recreating usable mugs... the agency will reimburse you for the scotch tape electrons that you used pasting these back together. +1.

Comment: *Beiber* is Canadian , right?

Answer (score 4):

So, I just joined so I can only attach 1 picture, so here is my completed set of images, thought I did make saves at each step along the way because I thought it would be interesting.

> [image]

No clue who these felons are, but I'm sure the data base will have their identities.

Answer (score 3):

Just finished!

> Charlie Sheen|Paul Reubens|Justin Bieber|Reese Witherspoon
> John Belushi|Robery Downing Jr.|Mel Gibson|Elvis
> O J Simpson|Kobe Bryant|Paris Hilton|Lindsay Lohan
> [image: unscrambled]