# Can you follow Directions?

Tags: visual, knowledge, english

**Unemployed? L[image]k no further!**

**Are you:**

- Able to follow directions?
- Able to read Flowcharts?
- Highly motivated?
- Able to count on your hands and feet without utilizing your big toes and thumbs?

Well then,

### ***This Is The Job For You!***

> **Simply answer the question posed below and you're** ***hired!***

### ***Act Now!***

[image]

<sub>Word Pool List:

KITCHEN, DOUBT, WALRUS, ARCANE, ARTISTIC, LAYOVER, EAST</sub>

Comment: Man, I love a good flow chart! :D

Comment: This is really good. Did you make this yourself? DVL2 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :P

Comment: @user477343 Thanks! I originally tried [this](https://code2flow.com/app), but it wasn't going well; not enough freedom, so I just made it in GIMP.

Comment: @user477343 87 Layers!!!

Comment: $87$ layers sounds like a lot, hahah. What is GIMP? It sounds like the *Great Internet Mersenne Prime Search* although that is GIMPS, hahah. Doing some research, did you mean [this](https://www.gimp.org/)? It looks pretty cool! :D

Comment: @user477343 lots of arrows and textboxes! Just copy and past new layer, easy peasy! Yes, that's GIMP. Very powerful, yet not quite Photoshop. Check out [this comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33894/how-would-you-like-your-face-scrambled#comment102121_33894) from one of my first puzzles!

Comment: great puzzle :P if more positions open up i'd love to join in :P :D

Comment: Flagged as spam :-P

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The answer is

> RIGHT AWAY!

And the question is

> When can you start?

Reasoning:

> The clue that fits the {0} box is WALRUS, first letter **W**.
>
> Then for barnyard animal, the word is Kitchen, the three letters we’re looking for are **HEN**.
>
> Then for {4,5,6}, the word is Arcane; for ability we want **CAN**.
>
> For {7,8} the first two letters are LA (Louisiana and Los Angeles), and the word is Layover. The two letters we want are **YO**.
>
> For {9}, b is the silent letter in Doubt, the middle letter is **U**.
>
> For {AB} the word is EAST, removing EA gives **ST**.
>
> For {CDE} the word is Artistic, we’re looking for Paul Simon’s pal **ART** Garfunkel.
>
> For {F} the character that appears 6 times is **?**
>
> Put all together (in increasing hex order) gives “When can you start?”, which means this might be a programming job too!

Being able to count on your hands and feet without using big toes or thumbs refers to

> The fact that we have 16 of those digits, hence the hexadecimal ordering.

Comment: Now for the discussion of salary perhaps? LOL

Comment: I’m broke, I’ll take whatever Chowzen is paying haha

Comment: One US cent per year? That's really cheap manpower LOL!

Comment: The job is yours! But sorry, this job's salary is a one-time lump sum of 15 RepCoins, payable as soon as I figure that I've milked this for all it was worth.

Comment: @Chowzen no rush -- think of all the tax I'm deferring by delayed receipt of my salary! In all seriousness though, this was a really fun puzzle! Very creative :D